# Django query latest()

Tags: django

I wan't to get the latest id of a table, and use this value as a filter

```
Lastrun=Runid.objects.latest('id')

query_hostinfo_results = HostinfoHist.objects.filter( runid = Lastrun )
```

if I enter the id manually, eg. runid = '1041'
everything works fine, but I can't query for Lastrun

I guess it's because I don't get a string or integer value back, but

Runid object (1041)

how I can get the value 1041 from this object

cheers
Funksen

Answer (score 1):

`Lastrun` is `Runid` object you can access id through `.`:

```
Lastrun=Runid.objects.latest('id')
query_hostinfo_results = HostinfoHist.objects.filter(runid=Lastrun.id)
```